# can't forward to another jsp from servlet invoked by ajax

Tags: ajax, servlets

I am calling a servlet using ajax code

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'servletName',
                data: {
                    userID: selectedID
                },
                type: 'post'
            });
```

I can print the value inside the servlet
but I can't forward to another jsp.....
The servlet code is

```
id = request.getParameter("userID");
System.out.println("Selected ID : "+id);

request.setAttribute("newID", id);

RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/newpage.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

if I call this servlet from a form submit button, it works.
but its not forwarding to another JSP from the ajax code.
is there any different way to do that????
Can anyone please help

Comment: And what does it do it it doesn't forward to the JSP? What happens? Any exception? How are you diagnosing that the forward doesn't happen?

Answer (score 3):

In `$.ajax`, add this:

```
dataType: 'text'
```

In success part, add this:

```
var url = "(your url)";  
$(location).attr('href', url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make understand the fact that when you send http request from ajax, it  means you are sending the request in separate thread other than main thread (the page itself from where you are sending the request). So redirection at the servlet will not reflect at the client end. In order to achieve this , send send back the URL  to which you want to redirect as a response to request and on success method of ajax simply use java script window.location(URL);

At servlet

```
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject()
String urlToRedirect = "test.jsp";
jobj.put("url",urlStr);
response.getWriter().write(jobj.toString());
```

At client end

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'servletName',
                data: {
                    userID: selectedID
                },
                type: 'post',
                success: function(data){
                  window.location = data.url;
                } 

            });
```